# Access Rails under /app/, not /app/public/

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, ruby-on-rails, .htaccess

I'm trying to deploy Rails 2.1.2 with Apache 2.2.10 and FastCGI (yeah, bad, ancient, ugly, I know).

My application can be accessed via `example.com/app/public/`, but I want to access it via `example.com/app/`.

In my .htaccess-File (in the app/-directory!) I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

How can I forward each request going to `app/` to `app/public/`? Every time I try this (like, with `RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$1 [QSA]`) I get a routing error:

```
No route matches "/app/" with {:method=>:get}
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your vhosts file seems to be pointing to the public folder, since your getting the routing error, so the rails environment is loaded.

First try to move your .htaccess inside the public folder.
The public folder should be the root of your website, for example, my rails app run on 
www.mydomain.com/ and if I put a file.html  on the public folder, i can access on www.mydomain.com/file.html .

But when you have a route on the routes.rb file, you can access on www.mydomain.com/myroute .

Sorry for the quick response.

Comment: Did you figure it out?